# Change order of buffers in Helm buffers list?

Tags: helm, buffers

When I run `M-x helm-buffers-list` it shows list of buffers in the order of their last visit.

[image]

Since I open quite  a few dired buffers, when `helm-buffers-list` is invoked, dired buffers are occupying lots of visible space.

How can i move all dired buffers to bottom and have other files at top?

Comment: I guess you can advice `helm-buffers-sort-transformer`. BTW, you can use `*!dired` to filter out all Dired buffers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`helm-buffers-sort-transformer` is used to sort buffers.

```lisp
(defun sort-dired-buffers (buffers)
  "Sort BUFFERS by moving all Dired buffers to the end."
  (let (dired-buffers other-buffers)
    (dolist (buf buffers)
      (if (with-current-buffer buf
            (eq major-mode 'dired-mode))
          (push buf dired-buffers)
        (push buf other-buffers)))
    (nreverse (append dired-buffers other-buffers))))

(defun helm-buffers-sort-dired-buffers (orig-fun &rest args)
  (sort-dired-buffers (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'helm-buffers-sort-transformer :around #'helm-buffers-sort-dired-buffers)
```